# How to call a variable from customer’s shipping address in Onepage checkout, step 3 shipping method?

Tags: php, magento

I need to call a variable that is a customer’s shipping address attribute, in Onepage checkout, step 3 shipping method:

In file

```
app/design/frontend/default/default/template/deliverydate/onepage/deliverydate.phtml
```

I already made successful tests in calling this variable with :

```
$numero_point_relais = $this->getCustomer()->getPrimaryShippingAddress()->getNumpr();
```

In

```
app/design/frontend/default/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
```

and in

```
app/design/frontend/default/default/template/dull/addressfields/onepage/shipping.phtml
```

But I can’t call this variable in deliverydate.phtml that is called in onepage/shipping_method.phtml with

```
php echo $this->getChildHtml('deliverydate')
```

How can I do that?
Make `$numero_point_relais` as global? How?
Make a module? Or is there an easier method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it eventually with:

```
$numero_point_relais = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getPrimaryShippingAddress()->getNumpr()
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$numero_point_relais` is not defined in deliverydate.php.

You can set customer Object with:

```
$variable = Mage::getModel('customer/session');
```